# Parse txt file that has columns not well seperated

Tags: python

How to read a `txt/data` file that has many columns that are not well seperated by rows (see the file below).

I want to extract some desired parameters only from each row of the file.

The contents of the file:

```
version=2
id  NumCompo    Species QuantumNumbers  Frequency   Eup Gup Aij FitFreq DeltaFitFreq    Vo  deltaVo FWHM_G  deltaFWHM_G FWHM_L  deltaFWHM_L Intensity   deltaIntensity  FitFlux deltaFitFlux    Freq.IntensityMax   V.IntensityMax  FWHM    IntensityMax    Flux1stMom  deltaFlux1stMom rms deltaV  Cal Size    TelescopePath   TelescopeName
None    None    None    None    MHz K   None    s-1 MHz MHz km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    K   K   K.km/s  K.km/s  MHz km/s    km/s    K   K.km/s  K.km/s  mK  km/s    %   arcsec  None    None
44003   1   CH3CHO  (18 1 17 2 _ 17 1 16 2) 350362.8435 163.4598498101699   74  0.0014741376966675667   350355.5848769065   Infinity    6.210933891166498   Infinity    1.739817511288065   Infinity    0.0 0.0 2.8623661141900496  Infinity    5.301075803032265   0.0 350355.5    6.2835599041722 1.7199802504879502  2.848570585251  4.899485148752622   0.0 3.854414571567953E-5    0.8289084198960507  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (18 1 17 0 _ 17 1 16 0) 350445.7777 163.41850853869101  74  0.0014742735891251069   350437.70831029414  0.12591692133973328 6.903042719892636   0.10771941048880102 2.203766561226652   0.2947187307742186  0.0 0.0 3.482121868378891   0.34484851265307565 8.168010359688692   0.0 350437.5    7.08124391130517    2.11135392209597    3.597269296646  7.595108638308943   0.0 204.05560763773454  0.8287143946045267  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (13 2 12 1 _ 12 1 11 2) 350572.1804 93.02188980281947   54  9.699686188970169E-5    350566.94541642064  NaN 4.476706032550229   NaN 0.4589727274204179  NaN 0.0 0.0 23.273694629520087  NaN 11.372220042377085  0.0 350566.40625    4.9377752090695495  1.3912897271407283  1.418276190758  1.9732330944498893  0.0 425.46913502384274  0.8284143332887641  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (8 6 3 3 _ 9 5 4 3) 350808.1122 318.0348265703963   34  1.075967688918428E-5    350801.2794264813   Infinity    5.839129418307394   Infinity    0.565736741450577   Infinity    0.0 0.0 11.264418715889377  Infinity    6.784303066688616   0.0 350801.75   5.436988227894669   1.3717772790578981  2.775228977203  3.806996055110165   0.0 156.0928146251678   0.8412065022978162  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (8 6 2 3 _ 9 5 5 3) 350808.1275 318.03482730468073  34  1.0759677371497151E-5   350801.2795084328   Infinity    5.852134153594954   Infinity    0.5663191176333013  Infinity    0.0 0.0 11.228477212030814  Infinity    6.769618049955546   0.0 350801.75   5.450063014554457   1.3717772790578981  2.775228977203  3.806996055110165   0.0 156.8862242548636   0.8412065022978162  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
```

Comment: Does the original file contain tabs between the columns that you replaced with spaces here?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* just split rows on spaces *if* the `QuantumNumbers` column didn't also contain spaces.

To allow this, you could use [a regex to replace all spaces withing brackets with commas](https://regex101.com/r/b9QIYZ/1).

So you could do something like the following:

```
import re
with open('f.txt') as fh:
    s = re.sub(r' (?=[^\(\)]*\))', ',', fh.read().strip())
    rows = [r.split() for r in s.split('\n')]
```

which would first calculate `s` as:

```
version=2
id  NumCompo    Species QuantumNumbers  Frequency   Eup Gup Aij FitFreq DeltaFitFreq    Vo  deltaVo FWHM_G  deltaFWHM_G FWHM_L  deltaFWHM_L Intensity   deltaIntensity  FitFlux deltaFitFlux    Freq.IntensityMax   V.IntensityMax  FWHM    IntensityMax    Flux1stMom  deltaFlux1stMom rms deltaV  Cal Size    TelescopePath   TelescopeName
None    None    None    None    MHz K   None    s-1 MHz MHz km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    K   K   K.km/s  K.km/s  MHz km/s    km/s    K   K.km/s  K.km/s  mK  km/s    %   arcsec  None    None
44003   1   CH3CHO  (18,1,17,2,_,17,1,16,2) 350362.8435 163.4598498101699   74  0.0014741376966675667   350355.5848769065   Infinity    6.210933891166498   Infinity    1.739817511288065   Infinity    0.0 0.0 2.8623661141900496  Infinity    5.301075803032265   0.0 350355.5    6.2835599041722 1.7199802504879502  2.848570585251  4.899485148752622   0.0 3.854414571567953E-5    0.8289084198960507  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (18,1,17,0,_,17,1,16,0) 350445.7777 163.41850853869101  74  0.0014742735891251069   350437.70831029414  0.12591692133973328 6.903042719892636   0.10771941048880102 2.203766561226652   0.2947187307742186  0.0 0.0 3.482121868378891   0.34484851265307565 8.168010359688692   0.0 350437.5    7.08124391130517    2.11135392209597    3.597269296646  7.595108638308943   0.0 204.05560763773454  0.8287143946045267  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (13,2,12,1,_,12,1,11,2) 350572.1804 93.02188980281947   54  9.699686188970169E-5    350566.94541642064  NaN 4.476706032550229   NaN 0.4589727274204179  NaN 0.0 0.0 23.273694629520087  NaN 11.372220042377085  0.0 350566.40625    4.9377752090695495  1.3912897271407283  1.418276190758  1.9732330944498893  0.0 425.46913502384274  0.8284143332887641  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (8,6,3,3,_,9,5,4,3) 350808.1122 318.0348265703963   34  1.075967688918428E-5    350801.2794264813   Infinity    5.839129418307394   Infinity    0.565736741450577   Infinity    0.0 0.0 11.264418715889377  Infinity    6.784303066688616   0.0 350801.75   5.436988227894669   1.3717772790578981  2.775228977203  3.806996055110165   0.0 156.0928146251678   0.8412065022978162  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (8,6,2,3,_,9,5,5,3) 350808.1275 318.03482730468073  34  1.0759677371497151E-5   350801.2795084328   Infinity    5.852134153594954   Infinity    0.5663191176333013  Infinity    0.0 0.0 11.228477212030814  Infinity    6.769618049955546   0.0 350801.75   5.450063014554457   1.3717772790578981  2.775228977203  3.806996055110165   0.0 156.8862242548636   0.8412065022978162  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
```

and then `rows` as a list of lists:

```
[['version=2']
 ['id', 'NumCompo', 'Species', 'QuantumNumbers', 'Frequency', 'Eup', 'Gup', 'Aij', 'FitFreq', 'DeltaFitFreq', 'Vo', 'deltaVo', 'FWHM_G', 'deltaFWHM_G', 'FWHM_L', 'deltaFWHM_L', 'Intensity', 'deltaIntensity', 'FitFlux', 'deltaFitFlux', 'Freq.IntensityMax', 'V.IntensityMax', 'FWHM', 'IntensityMax', 'Flux1stMom', 'deltaFlux1stMom', 'rms', 'deltaV', 'Cal', 'Size', 'TelescopePath', 'TelescopeName']
 ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'MHz', 'K', 'None', 's-1', 'MHz', 'MHz', 'km/s', 'km/s', 'km/s', 'km/s', 'km/s', 'km/s', 'K', 'K', 'K.km/s', 'K.km/s', 'MHz', 'km/s', 'km/s', 'K', 'K.km/s', 'K.km/s', 'mK', 'km/s', '%', 'arcsec', 'None', 'None']
 ['44003', '1', 'CH3CHO', '(18,1,17,2,_,17,1,16,2)', '350362.8435', '163.4598498101699', '74', '0.0014741376966675667', '350355.5848769065', 'Infinity', '6.210933891166498', 'Infinity', '1.739817511288065', 'Infinity', '0.0', '0.0', '2.8623661141900496', 'Infinity', '5.301075803032265', '0.0', '350355.5', '6.2835599041722', '1.7199802504879502', '2.848570585251', '4.899485148752622', '0.0', '3.854414571567953E-5', '0.8289084198960507', '0.0', '0.0', '/home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/', 'alma_400m']
 ['44003', '1', 'CH3CHO', '(18,1,17,0,_,17,1,16,0)', '350445.7777', '163.41850853869101', '74', '0.0014742735891251069', '350437.70831029414', '0.12591692133973328', '6.903042719892636', '0.10771941048880102', '2.203766561226652', '0.2947187307742186', '0.0', '0.0', '3.482121868378891', '0.34484851265307565', '8.168010359688692', '0.0', '350437.5', '7.08124391130517', '2.11135392209597', '3.597269296646', '7.595108638308943', '0.0', '204.05560763773454', '0.8287143946045267', '0.0', '0.0', '/home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/', 'alma_400m']
 ['44003', '1', 'CH3CHO', '(13,2,12,1,_,12,1,11,2)', '350572.1804', '93.02188980281947', '54', '9.699686188970169E-5', '350566.94541642064', 'NaN', '4.476706032550229', 'NaN', '0.4589727274204179', 'NaN', '0.0', '0.0', '23.273694629520087', 'NaN', '11.372220042377085', '0.0', '350566.40625', '4.9377752090695495', '1.3912897271407283', '1.418276190758', '1.9732330944498893', '0.0', '425.46913502384274', '0.8284143332887641', '0.0', '0.0', '/home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/', 'alma_400m']
 ['44003', '1', 'CH3CHO', '(8,6,3,3,_,9,5,4,3)', '350808.1122', '318.0348265703963', '34', '1.075967688918428E-5', '350801.2794264813', 'Infinity', '5.839129418307394', 'Infinity', '0.565736741450577', 'Infinity', '0.0', '0.0', '11.264418715889377', 'Infinity', '6.784303066688616', '0.0', '350801.75', '5.436988227894669', '1.3717772790578981', '2.775228977203', '3.806996055110165', '0.0', '156.0928146251678', '0.8412065022978162', '0.0', '0.0', '/home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/', 'alma_400m']
 ['44003', '1', 'CH3CHO', '(8,6,2,3,_,9,5,5,3)', '350808.1275', '318.03482730468073', '34', '1.0759677371497151E-5', '350801.2795084328', 'Infinity', '5.852134153594954', 'Infinity', '0.5663191176333013', 'Infinity', '0.0', '0.0', '11.228477212030814', 'Infinity', '6.769618049955546', '0.0', '350801.75', '5.450063014554457', '1.3717772790578981', '2.775228977203', '3.806996055110165', '0.0', '156.8862242548636', '0.8412065022978162', '0.0', '0.0', '/home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/', 'alma_400m']]
```

which you could then index with the syntax `rows[row index , column index]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have three lines of headers followed by the records, which are separated by varying whitespace and do not contain whitespace themselves, except for the QuantumNumbers field, which contains nine numbers within parentheses.. You can tackle this by:

- Looking at only the fourth line on
- Splitting each line on whitespace
- And then rejoining the quantum numbers

Like so:

```
import re

text = """version=2
id  NumCompo    Species QuantumNumbers  Frequency   Eup Gup Aij FitFreq DeltaFitFreq    Vo  deltaVo FWHM_G  deltaFWHM_G FWHM_L  deltaFWHM_L Intensity   deltaIntensity  FitFlux deltaFitFlux    Freq.IntensityMax   V.IntensityMax  FWHM    IntensityMax    Flux1stMom  deltaFlux1stMom rms deltaV  Cal Size    TelescopePath   TelescopeName
None    None    None    None    MHz K   None    s-1 MHz MHz km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    km/s    K   K   K.km/s  K.km/s  MHz km/s    km/s    K   K.km/s  K.km/s  mK  km/s    %   arcsec  None    None
44003   1   CH3CHO  (18 1 17 2 _ 17 1 16 2) 350362.8435 163.4598498101699   74  0.0014741376966675667   350355.5848769065   Infinity    6.210933891166498   Infinity    1.739817511288065   Infinity    0.0 0.0 2.8623661141900496  Infinity    5.301075803032265   0.0 350355.5    6.2835599041722 1.7199802504879502  2.848570585251  4.899485148752622   0.0 3.854414571567953E-5    0.8289084198960507  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (18 1 17 0 _ 17 1 16 0) 350445.7777 163.41850853869101  74  0.0014742735891251069   350437.70831029414  0.12591692133973328 6.903042719892636   0.10771941048880102 2.203766561226652   0.2947187307742186  0.0 0.0 3.482121868378891   0.34484851265307565 8.168010359688692   0.0 350437.5    7.08124391130517    2.11135392209597    3.597269296646  7.595108638308943   0.0 204.05560763773454  0.8287143946045267  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (13 2 12 1 _ 12 1 11 2) 350572.1804 93.02188980281947   54  9.699686188970169E-5    350566.94541642064  NaN 4.476706032550229   NaN 0.4589727274204179  NaN 0.0 0.0 23.273694629520087  NaN 11.372220042377085  0.0 350566.40625    4.9377752090695495  1.3912897271407283  1.418276190758  1.9732330944498893  0.0 425.46913502384274  0.8284143332887641  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (8 6 3 3 _ 9 5 4 3) 350808.1122 318.0348265703963   34  1.075967688918428E-5    350801.2794264813   Infinity    5.839129418307394   Infinity    0.565736741450577   Infinity    0.0 0.0 11.264418715889377  Infinity    6.784303066688616   0.0 350801.75   5.436988227894669   1.3717772790578981  2.775228977203  3.806996055110165   0.0 156.0928146251678   0.8412065022978162  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m
44003   1   CH3CHO  (8 6 2 3 _ 9 5 5 3) 350808.1275 318.03482730468073  34  1.0759677371497151E-5   350801.2795084328   Infinity    5.852134153594954   Infinity    0.5663191176333013  Infinity    0.0 0.0 11.228477212030814  Infinity    6.769618049955546   0.0 350801.75   5.450063014554457   1.3717772790578981  2.775228977203  3.806996055110165   0.0 156.8862242548636   0.8412065022978162  0.0 0.0 /home/dipen/Downloads/cassis3.9-160426-build6032/delivery/telescope/    alma_400m"""

records = text
lines = records.split("\n")

fields = []
WHITESPACE = re.compile(r"\s+")

for line in lines[3:]:
    current = WHITESPACE.split(line)
    current[3:12] = [" ".join(current[3:12])]
    fields.append(current)

print(fields)
```